# setting edittext border when is on focus

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, drawable, shapes

its something you may think is duplicated question but i could not found simple solution .

i want `edittext` to be with border when focus .

this is what i try'd , if you have simple or better solution i will be happy to read .

define shape `xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#80000000" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#5480F7" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />

</shape>
```

this simple `<shape>` create border with transparent background .

define xml for `edittext` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_border" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/notfocus"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

the problem here is that the xml that create the border is insert to my `edittext` as drawable meaning that i cant change the background image for the `edittext` .

i want my `edittext` to be with spcefic background image and when focus i want the image to stay but will be with border .

thanks .

Comment: you can create an image which you want to set as background with border. this will solve your requirement.

Comment: you are absolutely right , but i trying to avoid of adding more images to my project if that can be solved with code . and a code solution will help me understand some things better .

Comment: how will you add more images in this way? instead you will be creating a single image for your background and border.

Comment: but when the 'edittext' is out of focus i don't want it to be with border .

Comment: so in that case also image num is same one will b your background image with border and other will be just backgroung of focus set with border else without border

Comment: you able to solved it?

Comment: i solved it as you suggested . i was hope to do this with different way but as i understand there isn't one  . thanks !

Comment: Wecome. If my answer helped you then accept it as answer.

Comment: where ? i only see Droid Explorer answer

Comment: @ Jesus Dimrix now check. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make One background image with border and other will be just background of focus set with border else without border.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by two ways:

1. By creating two different image for the EditText.
2. By creating two different shape color for the EditText.

   1. By two different image:
      Just follow Siddhesh comment to achieve this.
   2. By Different shape for EditText:
      you have done right with this way. but i think you have enter wrong background color code to solid attribute.

add:

```
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
```

instead of:

```
   <solid android:color="#80000000" />
```

Hope this help you. If not then let me know. Will like to help you.

Enjoy Coding... :)